# Css,Html,Xml Style Sheet?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I am new to Asp.net and i saw many tutorials talking about css and Html and Xml Style sheet so please can anyone tell me what is the difference between those 3 Languages and what they are used for ? Also i want to know if we need to know HTML since when i was training on visual studio i saw that it is automatically generated when we add a control from the tool box . Thc for any help .

Answer (score 2):

HTML is a markup language for describing the semantics and structure of documents.

CSS is a language for describing how to present documents written in markup languages.

XSL is a collection of specifications for presenting and manipulating documents written in markup languages.

> [Do] we need to know HTML since when i was training on visual studio i saw that it is automatically generated when we add a control from the tool box

Yes. Visual Studio generates pretty poor markup.

Comment: Even outside of whether VS generates good markup, very rarely is auto-generated code enough for what you're doing.  It never fails that you need to do something that they didn't plan for.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between presenting and manipulating documents?

Comment: @KMan — One is how it looks, the other is how it changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not search for these:

- ### [**HTML**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) - [**Tutorial**](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_examples.asp)

> HTML, which stands for HyperText
>   Markup Language, is the predominant
>   markup language for web pages. A
>   markup language is a set of markup
>   tags, and HTML uses markup tags to
>   describe web pages. HTML is written in
>   the form of HTML elements consisting
>   of "tags" surrounded by angle brackets
>   (like ) within the web page
>   content. HTML tags normally come in
>   pairs like  **and** . The first tag
>   in a pair is the start tag, the second
>   tag is the end tag (they are also
>   called opening tags and closing tags).

**Example:**

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

- ### [Cascading Style Sheets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) - [Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_examples.asp)

> Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) is a
>   style sheet language used to describe
>   the presentation semantics (the look
>   and formatting) of a document written
>   in a markup language. Its most common
>   application is to style web pages
>   written in HTML and XHTML, but the
>   language can also be applied to any
>   kind of XML document, including SVG
>   and XUL.

**Example:**

```
<style type="text/css">
   body {color:red;}
   h1 {color:#00ff00;}
   p.ex {color:rgb(0,0,255);}
</style>
```

- ### [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) - [Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_examples.asp)

> Extensible Markup Language (XML) is a
>   set of rules for encoding documents in
>   machine-readable form. It is defined
>   in the XML 1.0 Specification
>   produced by the W3C, and several other
>   related specifications, all gratis
>   open standards.

**Example:**

```
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Comment: Eigh. Stay away from W3Schools.

Comment: Any reason? It has very basic information for a beginner. You got 2K votes on HTML tags. So you know better.

Answer (score 0):

The WikiPedia pages for HTML, XML and CSS will have a ton of information, as well as links to a ton more information.  So I'll just address the second part of the question...

If you're doing web development, it's definitely in your best interests to learn these things, *especially* HTML.  Sure, Visual Studio will generate stuff for you and all you *have* to do is drag and drop widgets onto a form.  However, if you don't actually know what it's doing for you or understand how the tool works then you're seriously limiting yourself.

Sometimes dragging an ASP .NET server control onto the form and setting a few properties is the best (as in quickest and easiest without significant side-effects) way to accomplish a particular task, sometimes it isn't.  If you're familiar with only one tool then you can only do what that one tool is designed to do.  You'll end up trying to fit other tasks into the scope of that tool, with potentially dismal results.

Visual Studio has a history of generating poor HTML.  It's certainly improved over the years, but it's not something on which you want to rely.  You can create simpler, more efficient, and ultimately easier to support code by having a better understanding of the underlying technologies involved and putting in a little work yourself.